# Cannot plot scatter and columnrange graph with multiple y-axis

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to plot a 'scatter' graph and 'columnrange' graph with multiple y-axis (ie two graphs stacked on top of each other with common x-axis). The scatter plot represents an event that occured in particular month and columnrange plot represents the time duration of an event. Both the graphs represent one and only one event type. I tried many things but was not able to produce a graph with my requirements.

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    title: { text: null },
    subtitle: { text: null },
    legend: { enabled: false },
    xAxis: { 
      type: 'datetime',
      title: { text: null }
    },
    yAxis: [{  
        top: 10,
      height: 60,
      offset: 0,
      title: { text: 'Plot 1'}
    },{
        top: 80,
      height: 60,
      offset: 0,
      title: { text: 'Plot 2'}
    }]
  });   
 chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.addSeries({ 
    yAxis: 0,
    type: 'scatter',
    marker: {
        enabled: true,
      symbol: 'triangle'
    },
    data: [[1356977700000,1], [1359656100000,1], [1364753700000,1]] 
  });
  chart.addSeries({ 
    yAxis: 1,
    type: 'columnrange',
    data: [[1356977700000, 1359656100000], [1362075300000, 1364753700000]]  
  });   
});
```

This is how I want to represent [columnrange graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EwW0.png)
This is how my [current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPY5U.png) looks like (second graph is behaving as 'column' graph instead of 'columnrange')

Also I would like to locate the scatter plot points in the middle of the area assigned for scatter plot. How can I achieve that. (currently I have set y=1 for scatter graph.)

Comment: You can set a min and mix for the y axis. If your y values are 1, set a min/max of 0/2, and your points will align in the middle.

Comment: yes that worked for the second part. But that does not fix my main issue. I am not able to plot a scatter plot and a columnrange plot in one graph with multiple y-axis.

Answer (score 1):

To have `columnrange` series inverted a chart needs to be inverted.

If you want for `columntange` points to share same horizontal line, then set same x value for points.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ubdxdqnh/